# How to close milestone automatically in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, milestone

I have created several milestones in Gitlab. But each time I complete it, I have to close it manually. It does not automatically close like the issues, or am I missing something. Is there some way of closing the milestone automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Not one directly implemented in GitLab, considering the way [`app/views/groups/milestones/show.html.haml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/0d0c539c047fdf3b7460d4044fc33a4505c1143b/app/views/groups/milestones/show.html.haml) is coded.

```
%span All issues for this milestone are closed. You may close the milestone now.
```

It doesn't seem to be [suggested either](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general?query=close%20milestone).

Plus there is a [pending issue 8751](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8751).